# Qt 4.7 QRegExp Email Address Validation

Tags: c#, c++, qt, validation, email

I have a good regular expression pattern for validating email addresses.  I've used it in php and I've used it in C#, not come across any problems (none yet).  I am hwoever having considerable trouble migrating the pattern and using it with qt's QRegExp.

Can anyone help me?

```
// C# version
public bool isEmailAddress(string strEmailAddr)
{
    if (strEmailAddr.Length == 0)
        return false;

    Regex rTest = new Regex(@"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return rTest.Match(strEmailAddr).Success;
}

// #C++/Qt 4.7 version ... not working
bool isEmailAddress(QString strEmailAddr)
{
    if ( strEmailAddr.length() == 0 ) return false;

    QString strPatt = "\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b";
    QRegExp rx(strPatt);
    return rx.exactMatch(strEmailAddr);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C#'s raw string made it a bit easier to write but since you're dealing with C++, you need to escape the backslashes:

```
QString strPatt = "\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b";
```

Comment: cheers mate, I knew it was something and nothing, my bad.  I had funnily done a double quote for the dot.  Anyway had an issue with Qt:CaseSensitivity enum not being in scope via #include <Qt> so: QString strPatt = "\\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\\b";

Comment: If you want your regex to be case insensitive as given in the c# example use this constructor. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qregexp.html#QRegExp-2 i.e QRegExp rx(strPatt,Qt::CaseInsensitive); othwerwise you may not get exact behavior as c# program.

Comment: OrcunC, I was trying to use setCaseSensitivity but was having a scope issue for those enums, I will change the constructor instead.  It was adapted with A-Za-z until now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

here you can scape your strings with this built-in function:

```
QRegExp::escape(QSTRING_HERE)
```